# How to find QnA Maker settings to send in Bot Framework SDK?

Tags: javascript, botframework, artificial-intelligence, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I need to find the information below

QnAKnowledgebaseId=
QnAAuthKey
QnAEendpointHostName=

to insert it into the .env file of the bot framework i created and then connect it to my knowledge base. I didn't find this information because now the website it's all Cognitive services at Microsoft.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should be able to find QnAAuthKey and QnAEendpointHostName on the Azure portal, under respective language service.
   [image]
2. You should be able to fine QnAKnowledgebaseId in the language portal, it is the name of your KB you have provided in free text form

[image]

More specific are here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/authoring#create-a-project

The SDK sample is here to use,
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/12.customQABot/Bots/CustomQABot.cs#L109